# How to pass an object when navigating to a new view in PRISM?

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, prism

As far as I know, currently PRISM allows to pass strings, but doesn't allow to pass objects. I would like to know what are the ways of overcoming this issue.

I want to pass a list collection. The UriQuery isn't usefull in my case, what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have my own technique.

I extract the hash code of the object and save it in a `Dictionary`, with the hash code as the key and the object as the value of the pair.

Then, I attach the hash code to the `UriQuery`.

After, I only have to get the hash code that comes from the Uri on the target view and use it to request the original object from the `Dictionary`.

Some example code:

Parameter repository class:

```
public class Parameters
{
    private static Dictionary<int, object> paramList =
        new Dictionary<int, object>();

    public static void save(int hash, object value)
    {
        if (!paramList.ContainsKey(hash))
            paramList.Add(hash, value);
    }

    public static object request(int hash)
    {
        return ((KeyValuePair<int, object>)paramList.
                    Where(x => x.Key == hash).FirstOrDefault()).Value;
    }
}
```

The caller code:

```
UriQuery q = null;
Customer customer = new Customer();
q = new UriQuery();
Parameters.save(customer.GetHashCode(), customer);
q.Add("hash", customer.GetHashCode().ToString());

Uri viewUri = new Uri("MyView" + q.ToString(), UriKind.Relative);
regionManager.RequestNavigate(region, viewUri);
```

The target view code:

```
public partial class MyView : UserControl, INavigationAware
{
// some hidden code

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        int hash = int.Parse(navigationContext.Parameters["hash"]);
        Customer cust = (Customer)Parameters.request(hash);
    }
}
```

That's it.

Comment: Just one thing, what do you think.. is better that Parameters were be an static class or not a service?

Comment: Well. That was a workaround I did when I was trying to do the feature work. Any kind improvement are welcome. If you improve the example, share it here. ;) bye

Comment: Since you are putting the instance in the Parameter "cache" and then passing the "key", you might want to just create a new Guid (which is unique, versus a hash, which is not), and release the object from the cache after it is retrieved.

Comment: As @BahriGungor has stated, a hash is not a unique key and should not be used as such.

Answer (score 6):

Prism 5 and 6 : The NavigationParameters class can now be used to pass object parameters during navigation, using the overloads of the RequestNavigate method of a Region or RegionManager instance.

Comment: it would be better to add an example or even a link

Answer (score 1):

You can create an PRISM event with 'object' getter/setter. Rise event with your object casted or not casted to 'object' inside event (depends if event implementation 'shared' like in famous 'Infrastructure' projects) and then Navigate to Region. In ViewModel that implement Region - Subscribe() to above event, receive it and store locally and then just wait for 'OnNavigatedTo' function call. When OnNavigatedTo function called you already have the object/class/struct and can run the ViewModel.

For example - Event class:

```
namespace CardManagment.Infrastructure.Events
{
    using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Events;

    /// <summary>
    /// Event to pass 'Selected Project' in between pages
    /// </summary>
    public class SelectedProjectViewEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<SelectedProjectViewEvent>
    {
        public object SelectedPorject { get; set; }
    }
}
```

'Calling' class

```
/// <summary>
/// Called when [back to project view].
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">The e.</param>
public void OnBackToProjectView(CancelEditProjectEvent e)
{
   eventAggregator.GetEvent<SelectedProjectViewEvent>().Publish(new SelectedProjectViewEvent()
   {
       SelectedPorject = selectedProject
   });

   regionManager.RequestNavigate(WellKnownRegionNames.ProjectViewRegion, new System.Uri("ProjectDetailsView", System.UriKind.Relative));
 }
```

And this on 'Receiver' class

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the implementer has been navigated to.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="navigationContext">The navigation context.</param>
    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        if (this.SelectedProject == null)   // <-- If event received untill now
            this.ShouldBeVisible = false;
        else
            this.ShouldBeVisible = true;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out how to pass objects if you are using an IOC and want to use constructor injection.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170410/1798889